# interpreting an explain statement for a slow query on MySQL 5.7.36

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a question about some performance problems we are having that are a bit beyond me. When we do this query on about 2M reviews, it takes about 20 seconds but seems like it should be hitting indexes both times. Both obj_id and id have indexes. Is the primary query here the `select * from post`? The db server is MySQL 5.7.36.

```
mysql> explain select * from post where id in
  (select max(id) from post
    where obj_id IN (1709768, 1816027)
    and obj_type="Review"
    group by obj_id);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | post  | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | 2408603 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | post  | NULL       | range | idx_post      | idx_post | 198     | NULL |       5 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this index:

```
INDEX(obj_type, obj_id, id)
```

This looks like a [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) query; it may have a better formulation.

If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE post`.